# Installed GMP but cannot see it

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, gmp

I am trying to install the Parma Polyhedra Library,which has GMP as a dependency in the configure file. So I downloaded GMP, ran `"./configure --enable-cxx; make; sudo make install;"` and it all seemed to work without issues. I tried this several times with different versions of GMP, no error messages.

However, when I try to run the configure file for the PPL library, I still get these issues:

```
Checking for the GMP library version 4.1.3 or above... no
configure: error: Cannot find GMP version 4.1.3 or higher.
GMP is the GNU Multi-Precision library:
see http://www.swox.com/gmp/ for more information.
When compiling the GMP library, do not forget to enable the C++ interface:
add --enable-cxx to the configuration options.
```

I also tried the running the PPL configure with `"./configure  --with-gmp-include=/usr/local/include  --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib"`, but am getting the same error.

I am using an old Ubuntu with 32bit.

What do I need to do to make sure that my system realises that I installed GMP?

Comment: The general strategy is to look in config.log to see exactly what failed (did it try to compile some test program with some options? And got what error message?).

Comment: If you don't need a recent PPL, Ubuntu should have a package. Even for GMP, the Ubuntu package should work.